# Why Django does admin change page displays html instead of link after upgrading from Django 1.11 to 2.2?

Tags: django, django-admin

I recently upgraded to Django 2.2 and now the HTML of my link is display instead of an actual link.

Here is the code I suspect has changed in behavior:

```
class RequestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('id', 'status', )
    list_display = ('detail_link', 'status', 'requester', 'added', 'type', 'change_description', 'approve_or_deny')

    ... omitted for brevity ...

    # ID in list is rendered as link to open request details page
    def detail_link(self, obj):
        return '<a href="%s%s%s%s%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % (('https://' if self.request.is_secure() else 'http://'),
                                                self.request.META['HTTP_HOST'],
                                                (settings.GUI_ROOT if settings.GUI_ROOT != '/' else ''),
                                                '/#/requests/', obj.id, obj.id)
```

Before this would render a link.  But now if renders this text instead:

```
<a href="http://app-dev-001.example.com:5200/gui/#/requests/1" target="_blank">1</a>
```

Comment: Red Cricket, always use `https` connection, just use redirection on the nginx side.

Comment: Use f-strings instead of % operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is much more different from 2.0 version

Use [format_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) for your link

P.S. I'd even suggest you to use `Django 3.0` to avoid similar problems in the future